# Update ActiveMQ Artemis client libraries in JBoss EAP 7.4

Tags: java, jms, jboss7.x, activemq-artemis

**JMS servers:**
ActiveMQ Artemis cluster - version 2.28.0

**JMS clients:**
Apache Camel routes embedded in JBoss EAP 7.4 application servers

What is the recommended/appropriate way to update the ActiveMQ Artemis client libraries to version 2.28.0? There is little documentation available for that.

Comment: Asking "what is the best way" to do _anything_ is going to lead to opinion-based answers because what is "best" is dependent on the specifics of your use-case. What is considered best in one context is different from what is best in another context even for seemingly simple questions like this. Please reword your post to ask a clear, concrete question rather than an open-ended, opinion-based question.

Comment: How is your Camel application currently loading ActiveMQ Artemis libraries? I assume it's using a module of some kind. Is that correct? Please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the question as per your suggestion. I will add the answer to the second comment after ascertaining the current process of loading ActiveMQ Artemis libraries.

Comment: Also Artemis JMS client should be compatible with a newest version of the broker. Do you have a specific need to upgrade the client libraries version ?

Comment: Any feedback here on how your Camel application is currently loading ActiveMQ Artemis libraries?